# Submit form using jquery with preventDefault() method

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I am trying to submit a form using Jquery. My goal is to submit the form to the server using .ajax. After the submission, the content of the form will go to the page without page being reloaded (I suppose e.preventDefault() below will achieve this). Code is listed below.

But when I click submit, the form seems to be reloaded. What is wrong with my code?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<script src="http:////code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>    
<script type='text/javascript'>

        $("#submitForm").submit(function(e){

            e.preventDefault();
        // some ajax code to submit the form

            var container = document.getElementById("div2");
            var node = document.createTextNode("put form contents here");           
            container.appendChild(node);          

        });

</script>

</head>

<body>
<h1>edit form here</h1>

<div id = "div1">
<form id = "submitForm">
    <input type = "text"/>
    <input type = "submit"  value = "submit"/>
</form>
</div>

<h1>show form contents here</h1>

<div id = "div2">

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[EDITED]: This code works for me. Just put it after body section.

```
    $("#submitForm").submit(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      var container = document.getElementById("div2");
      var node = document.createTextNode("put form contents here");           
      container.appendChild(node);     
    });
```

Comment: I updated my answer. This script should be after body, then you are sure that your elements are rendered, so event can be attached properly to them.

Comment: the src for jquerry was wrong in my code. I updated. now everything works!

Answer (score 0):

The script is being executed before form appears in document.

Fix:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $("#submitForm").submit(function(e){

            e.preventDefault();
        // some ajax code to submit the form

            var container = document.getElementById("div2");
            var node = document.createTextNode("put form contents here");           
            container.appendChild(node);          

        });
});
```

This will execute your code when DOMContentLoaded event fires

Comment: I change the code as you suggested. It still does not work. Weird.

Comment: That strange. Did you try to reload your page with ctrl + r ?

Comment: add some console.log calls in first lines of ready function. Check if everything is executed